# I want to extract data below a heading from a resume, but its not totally efficient its not identifying some of the headings properly what can I do?

Tags: python, validation, nlp, spacy, data-cleaning

In some cases when it identifies the heading it is not able to identify next heading and print the data in next heading into old heading itself, I will show you a example.
Expected output:-
Skills:
• Proficient in Tensorflow, Pytorch, Tableau and Python
• Adverse knowledge in Database languages and technologies
• Go-getter and a team player
• Specializing in project testing and debugging
Activities:
As a team player, I enjoy playing the guitar in a band. I admire dancing and have been learning classical
for a while now.

(Both the Skills and Activities should be identified as different heading)

My output:-
Skills: • Proficient in Tensorflow, Pytorch, Tableau and Python • Adverse knowledge in Database languages and technologies • Go-getter and a team player • Specializing in project testing and debugging Activities: As a team player, I enjoy playing the guitar in a band. I admire dancing and have been learning classical for a while now.
(It is printing the activities part in skills section itself, it is not able to identify the activities heading differently)

import spacy
def differentiate_headings_and_content(resume_text):
# Load the pre-trained English language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

```
# Process the resume text
doc = nlp(resume_text)

# Initialize variables to store the current heading and its content
current_heading = None
current_content = ""

# Initialize a dictionary to store the identified headings and their content
headings_and_content = {}

# Define the set of headings
headings = {
    "EDUCATION": ["education","academic background","educational qualifications","educational history",
                  "academic achievements","academic credentials","education and training","educational experience",
                  "academic record","formal education","educational highlights","educational background",
                  "degrees and certifications","educational attainment","professional education","academic profile",
                  "relevant education","education and degrees","educational accomplishments","academic training",
                  "qualifications and education"],

    "SKILLS": ["skills","core competencies","key skills","technical proficiencies","areas of expertise",
               "technical skills","software proficiencies","specialized skills","qualifications",
               "strengthsskillset","professional skills","language proficiencies","industry knowledge",
               "tools and technologies","functional skills","interpersonal skills","leadership skills",
               "transferable skills","relevant skills"],

    "EXTRA_CURRICULAR": ["extra-curricular", "activities","activities and involvement","leadership experience",
                         "volunteering and community engagement","community service","professional development",
                         "skills and interests","relevant hobbies","additional engagements","special projects",
                         "personal initiatives","non-academic pursuits","club memberships","campus involvement",
                         "team memberships","creative pursuits","athletics and sports","social and cultural activities",
                         "philanthropy and fundraising","entrepreneurial ventures","professional affiliations"],

    "CERTIFICATION": ["certification","professional certifications","certification highlights","certified achievements",
                      "credentialing","certifications and licenses","industry certifications","certification portfolio",
                      "certified expertise","certified skills","certification credentials","professional designations",
                      "certification accomplishments","certification training","certified proficiencies",
                      "certified specializations","accredited certifications","industry-recognized certifications",
                      "professional licenses","certified training and development","validated certifications"],

    "EXPERIENCE" : ["experience","experiences"],

    "CAREER_OBJECTIVE": ["career", "objective", "career objective", "career", "objective","professional summary",
                         "career summary","profile","career profile","professional profile","overview",
                         "summary of qualifications","key skills and experience","career highlights",
                         "career goals","personal statement","value proposition","core competencies",
                         "skills summary","expertise summary","career focus","career objectives",
                         "professional goals","introduction"],

    "DECLARATION": ["declaration","professional affirmation","personal statement","commitment statement",
                    "career pledge","ethical declaration","statement of integrity","career promise",
                    "professional vow","professional code","career commitment","statement of professionalism",
                    "values statement","professional oath","professional assurance","career dedication",
                    "ethical pledge","personal integrity statement","career ethics statement","career mission statement",
                    "professional conduct statement","activities","Activities"]
}

# Iterate over each sentence in the resume
for sentence in doc.sents:
    # Convert the sentence to lowercase for easier matching
    sentence_text = sentence.text.lower()

    # Check if the sentence matches any of the headings
    for heading, keywords in headings.items():
        if any(keyword in sentence_text for keyword in keywords):
            # If a new heading is encountered, store the previous heading and its content (if any)
            if current_heading:
                if current_heading not in headings_and_content:
                    headings_and_content[current_heading] = []
                headings_and_content[current_heading].append(current_content.strip())
            current_heading = heading
            current_content = ""
            break

    # If a heading has been identified, add the sentence to its content
    if current_heading:
        current_content += sentence.text + " "

# Add the last heading and its content to the dictionary
if current_heading:
    if current_heading not in headings_and_content:
        headings_and_content[current_heading] = []
    headings_and_content[current_heading].append(current_content.strip())

# Clean the extracted content
for heading, content in headings_and_content.items():
    if isinstance(content, str):
        headings_and_content[heading] = clean_data([content])[0]
    elif isinstance(content, list):
        headings_and_content[heading] = clean_data(content)[0]    

return headings_and_content
```